# For Loop With Different Signs

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me how to shorten this code like with a for loop or something? The if statement doesn't change completely, just the "+" and "-".

```
# "+" and "-" changes

if (y[0] + 1, y[1]) in p:
    x.append((y[0] + 1, y[1]))
    p.remove((y[0] + 1, y[1]))

if (y[0] - 1, y[1]) in p:
    x.append((y[0] - 1, y[1]))
    p.remove((y[0] - 1, y[1]))
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for delta in (-1, 1):
    if (y[0] + delta, y[1]) in p:
        x.append((y[0] + delta, y[1]))
        p.remove((y[0] + delta, y[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for s in [+1, -1]:
    if (y[0] + s, y[1]) in p:
        x.append((y[0] + s, y[1]))
        p.remove((y[0] + s, y[1]))
```